# Why does PyCharm's debugger open parse.py?

Tags: python, pycharm

I know this question has been asked here, I looked at the search thingy and still, no answer at like 5 other topics helped me...
anyway, I have this code:

```
def string_list(amount):
    #  5-hello, my, dear, friend, good - VV
    """
    This function receives the amount of words and put them in a list.
    :param amount: The amount of strings to write.
    :type amount: int
    :return: The list built with the strings.
    :rtype: list
    """
    empty_list = []
    for strings in range(1, amount + 1):
        phrase = input("Please enter your word: ")
        empty_list.append(phrase)
    return empty_list
```

something is weird but.. it keeps doing parse annoying thingy once it reach input, how do i stop it from happening? [image: see parse annoying]

even when i tried doing it not on def, it kept doing it..

```
amount = 5
empty_list = []
for strings in range(1, amount + 1):
    phrase = input("Please enter your word: ")
    empty_list.append(phrase)
print(empty_list)
```

the code is working good, but if i try to debug, it wont get inputs for some reason... it wasnt like that before... any way of fixing it?

EDIT, EDIT:
Tried a few stuff I was told here, but its still not working:

```
def string_list(amount):
    #  5-hello, my, dear, friend, good - VV
    """
    This function receives the amount of words and put them in a list.
    :param amount: The amount of strings to write.
    :type amount: int
    :return: The list built with the strings.
    :rtype: list
    """
    empty_list = []
    for strings in range(1, amount + 1):
        phrase = input("Please enter your word: ")
        print(phrase)
        empty_list.append(phrase)
    return empty_list

x = string_list(5)
print(x)
```

I was told i can add print to return, but i still keep getting parse thingy...
can anyone help me with it? :(

Comment: Try to print every phrase you get by user, maybe your problem solved

Comment: your question is quite unclear

Comment: editor/IDE? no idea what it is, you mean pycharm?

about devreddit:
the problem is parse, im trying to debug while doing inputs, but its not working well... look at the codes and pictures

Comment: So when you debug your code in PyCharm, the debugger steps into (opens) this parse.py file?

Comment: I've added that to the question title to clarify your question.  Please try to be more precise when describing problems: "something is weird but.. it keeps doing parse annoying thingy" is very vague.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/part-1-debugging-python-code.html#step).

Comment: @snakecharmerb Hey, it helped me so much, finally I can debug, didnt know it was because of it... but also ,can you explain me the difference between the two? edit: if i could do an upvote or something else like monitin, i would have done it, thanks alot!! finally i can debug proprely

Answer (score 0):

If you want to learn how to debug properly you should watch tutorials on how to do so, like this-

https://youtu.be/QJtWxm12Eo0

Also, if you just want to print each iteration the `phrase` you could just add `print` Statement to your code:

```
amount = 5
empty_list = []
for strings in range(1, amount + 1):
    phrase = input("Please enter your word: ")
    print(phrase)
    empty_list.append(phrase)
print(empty_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!!
Ill watch the video pretty soon, just a quick question before it.
if Im doing it a function and I want to return, if ill add print, wont it be problematic? that's the problem, I need it for the function.

Comment: You can add `print` statements to the a function no problem here. A function can both return and print in Python.

Comment: Oh Thanks, ill try it!